# How to modify the title for a custom page of a module in prestashop

Tags: title, prestashop-1.6

I have written a new module with its own page listing few products. I now want to modify the title of the page as it is currently showing only the shop name. What I found out was that for this, I need to include a separate header.tpl and pass the title as argument. If so, how do I tell prestashop not to include the default header.tpl file. Also since I just want to modify the title, is there any other way to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

From the back-office, go to **Preferences** > **SEO & URLs**.

You should have a page registered that corresponds to the `FrontController` in your module or the `FrontController` that calls your module's hook (whichever fits your use case). If you don't, go ahead and create one.

Once the page appears in the URL list, you can edit the page title among other things.

Comment: Thanks. I did edit the Page Title but I am still not able to see the title on the page. However I do see title on product pages. If I follow this answer, https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/443481-cant-change-meta-title-from-modules-front-controller/ I am able to set the title from the module's initContent method but it is hardcoded. I would want to use the title that I set in my SEO & URLs section.